# configure standard sendmail install to accept outside connections and forward mail to gmail account

Tags: sendmail, smtp, mail-forwarding

I want to have some mail accounts on my domain (contact, webaster) redirected to my gmail account.

In order to do this I installed sendmail.

Default install (`apt-get install sendmail` on ubuntu server 10.04) has local daemon, and only accepts delivery to local accounts.

To forward I activated virtusertable on sendmail.mc adding the line `FEATURE(virtusertable)dnl`, edited the file /etc/mail/virtusertable and added the lines:

```
webmaster@mydomain.com   myaccount@gmail.com
contact@mydomain.com    myaccount@gmail.com
```

finally, I did `m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf` and `make virtusertable.db`, and edited the sendmail.cf to change the daemon listenting on my external ip's interface instead of 127.0.0.1.

As a result I can send email to, let's say root@mydomain.com from any host and it gets to my server's root local mail account, but on the forwarded accounts (webmaster, contact) I don't get any delivery error message but neither any forwarded mail on my gmail account, or local mail on the server like it happens with root@mydomain.com which is not forwarded using virtusertable.

I guess I would like to know what's happening (I don't even know where is the log file), and how to fix it. And also how can I change the daemon config on sendmail.mc to allow outside connections instead of just local ones without having to edit sendmail.cf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot about virtusertable and edited `/etc/mail/aliases` file instead, adding the lines:

```
webmaster:    myaccount@gmail.com
contact:      myaccount@gmail.com
```

then I executed `newaliases` and everything peachy.

Now, about proper config of the daemon to listen on 127.0.0.1 and also on any other interface editing sendmail.mc instead of sendmail.cf I've found this: http://lists.samba.org/archive/linux/2002-August/004310.html

which basically tells to simply place dnl at the front of the line which specifies the daemon options, which will make sendmail listen on all available network interfaces. e.g:

```
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS('Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')
```

of course after doing that it's necessary to rebuild the config files (`m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf`) and restart sendmail.